# Pulling Duplicate Record with max value in PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sas, duplicates, max

I'm working with a database with multiple duplicate records.  It has an active record indicator that is not correct, so I basically have to create an active indicator manually using the date for the record.

See an example of the data below:

```
application_nbr date             Amount
138352          4/26/2017    $10,000.00 
138352          4/22/2017    $9,500.00 
553652          5/1/2017     $2,500.00 
332621          4/15/2017    $7,500.00 
332621          4/3/2017     $8,500.00
```

I need a query that will pull this from the above:

```
application_nbr date         Amount
138352          4/26/2017    $10,000.00 
553652          5/1/2017     $2,500.00 
332621          4/15/2017    $7,500.00
```

I'm really not sure how to tackle this one.  I'm thinking some kind of a subquery using max(date)?  I know I can't use functions like max in the where clause.  Is there a fairly simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use MAX() in HAVING clause instead. ie `having date=max(date)`

Comment: @Reeza I tried using having with max(date) and it only pulled the records with the highest date in the table.  It just pulled the records with a date of 5/1/2017

Comment: Did you include a GROUP BY for the application_nbr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table_name a
JOIN (SELECT application_nbr, MAX(date) AS max_date
      FROM table_name
      GROUP BY application_nbr) b
ON a.application_nbr = b.application_nbr
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not explain my issue appropriatly on my post.  I made edits to be more accurate.  There are other fields in the database that I do not want to use a summary function on.  That is why GROUP BY in the way you recommend.

Comment: "where" condition is not required as you are taking inner join

Comment: I have not DV you.

Comment: @G.Arima You are right about where clause. I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using **SAS dataset**:

```
proc sort data=have;
by application_nbr date;
run;

data want;
set have;
by application_nbr date;
if first.date;
run;
```

Or if you really want to use **proc sql** then

```
proc sql;  
select a.*,b.amount
from
(select application_nbr,max(date) as date 
 from have 
 group by application_nbr) a
inner join
have b
on a.application_nbr=b.application_nbr; 
quit;
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.  In `proc sql`, I would go for re-merging:

```
proc sql;
    select t.*
    from (select t.*, max(date) as maxdate
          from t
         )
    where date = maxdate;
```

The typical way to do this in SQL is:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select application_nbr, max(date) as maxdate
      from t
      group by application_nbr
     ) tt
     on t.application_nbr = tt.application_nbr;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Proc sql;
   select * from have group by application_nbr having date=max(date);
quit;
```